Article Submission and Approval
My articles were closed three different time without reasonable excuse.
I don't know who is responsible for article review. This will be the third time my article will be closed because of non-complete article submitted.
The instruction for submission is to submit a draft and should not be a full draft. Why will someone be asking for full draft before approval. The below image shows what is required for approval.

Both @Microsoft and @R Language, I have experienced these acts.
I submitted a title, respective tags, an abstract that show my ideas and outlines with even introduction content, but yet three articles have been closed in three consecutive times.
I have 25 years' experience in IT and 19 consecutive years in Infrastructure and software development. I think in my opinion, there should be a robust moderation or moderator, this should be checked and there should be away to send message to the reviewers.
There should be clarification on this issue.
Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/propose-article
https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/edit/78325526

ChatGPT is not allowed here. Please don't dump ChatGPT-written content into the site.

It's absolutely not chatGPT

If it's a ChatGPT or even plagiarism content issues, why won't the moderator or reviewer say it?

The reviewer gave you very clear feedback: "This is an incomplete and vague conten. It has no info about implementation and no code. We cannot approve an article with the hope that you'd provide something useful afterwards. Put aside that the scope of what you've "shown" is way too broad anyway and I have a hard time to imagine it as a good fit for articles."

The guideline says: We should "submit an outline summarizing your key ideas for approval". Not full content with code

@SinaSalam - "If it's a ChatGPT or even plagiarism content issues, why won't the moderator or reviewer say it?" - To avoid the situation where the author spends time trying to modify ChatGPT responses into something that might appear to be acceptable.  ChatGPT responses even those modified by a human are not allowed. As for plagiarized content, it has no business on Stack Overflow, and will be deleted without feedback. We don't interact with users who plagiarize content.

Taking the most generous reading of your article, it reads like an intro for a formal paper of some sort. That's not a good fit for Articles. Worse is you just posted the abstract with this at the end

After the approval, I will provide the full article

That's quite a bit of faith you're asking for. Approve first, then useful content later? That's not how we operate.
The idea there is that an Article is a short read about a topic (here's a useful example from the R collective). A paper abstract doesn't fit that format. Even a full entry of your paper seems self-promotional.
This isn't useful as-is, and it was rightfully rejected. Please make it a standalone Article that is full academic paper, nor promising useful content from edits later.

I noticed your comments about this line in the Help Center

For the first version that is submitted, we encourage users to provide a detailed outline or summary of the proposed article (rather than drafting the complete article) in the event the subject matter would be declined. Hit the "Submit for review" button.

The goal of a summary is to propose a topic that may be rejected by the community. A research paper abstract is not what the community is looking for.

Your explanation make sense; it is clear to me than rejections.
